# How can i use a cmd variable in a powershell command?

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, environment-variables

I have created a simple .bat file. In this batch file i have a variable named **urlExample** which is equal to  "example.com".
In the same batch file i want to use this variable **urlExample** in a powershell command.

Specifically, consider the following code:

```
@echo off
set urlExample = "example.com"


powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& {$WebClient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient;$WebClient.DownloadFile($urlExample,"C:\.....somePath")
```

How could i achieve using the **urlExample** inside the WebClient command?

P.s. I don't want to simply put the url in the DownloadFile's first argument. I want to pass it with a batch variable.

Thanks in advance

Comment: when executing the powershell command, it's still a batch variable and has to be referenced as `%urlExample %`. (If you don't want the space, use the correct `set` syntax: `set "urlExample=example.com"` - quote it when used if needed: `powershell ....DownloadFile("%urlExample%","C:\...`)

Comment: As an aside: There's no reason to use `"& { ... }"` in order to invoke code passed to PowerShell's CLI via the `-Command` (`-c`) parameter - just use `"..."` directly. Older versions of the [CLI documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh) erroneously suggested that `& { ... }` is required, but this has since been corrected.

Comment: This seems to be a follow up question on your now deleted question, if so, you are taking the wrong approach in getting the hash.

Comment: @Gerhard i managed to get the hash with powershell after trying infinite ways...
@ mklement0 thanks:) good to know
@ Stephan your comment made this work, thank you.

Comment: @bd55, I understand that you didn't want everyone to know this was for malware, but apart from the poor and inefficient coding in your batch file, _[posted in the chat discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251979/discussion-between-mklement0-and-bd55)_, I'm not sure that your intent of obfuscating the URI, presumably ```httPs:\\Pastebin.com\raw\bNMQZW1C```, is robust either. It presumes that the end user does not have a redirected 'all users' profile directory, or has selected something other than `%systemdrive%\Windows\System32\cmd.exe` for their command specifier/interpreter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- In `cmd.exe`, *all* variables are also *environment* variables, such as `%urlExample%` in your case, and *child* processes - such as a call to [`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe), the Windows PowerShell CLI, *inherit* environment variables.

  - By contrast, PowerShell also has *shell*(-only) variables (e.g., `$urlExample`, limited to that session only), whereas *environment* variables must be accessed via the `env` namespace (e.g. `$env:urlExample` - see the conceptual [about_Environment_Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Environment_Variables) help topic).
- While you can use *string interpolation* on the `cmd.exe` side to "bake in" the *values* of `cmd.exe`-defined environment variables, by embedding `%urlExample%` in the `-Command` argument, it is more robust to let *PowerShell* access the environment variable, by referencing `$env:urlExample`.

Therefore:

```bash
@echo off

:: Note: No spaces around "=", double-quote the name *and* the value.
set "urlExample=example.com"

:: Note the reference to $env:urlExample
:: Embedded " chars. are escaped as \"
powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "$WebClient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient; $WebClient.DownloadFile($env:urlExample, \"C:\.....somePath\")"
```

Note:

- `-ExecutionPolicy Bypass` isn't strictly needed in this case, given that no execution of a script *file* is (`.ps1`) is involved here (whether directly with `-File` or indirectly, as part of a `-Command` argument).
- However, given that the effective [execution policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Execution_Policies) also applies in less obvious scenarios when you use `-Command` (the default parameter of `powershell.exe`)<sup>[1]</sup> - such as (possibly implicitly) loading a *module* that is either a script module (`*.psm1`) and / or contains formatting / type-definition data (`*.ps1xml`) - using `-ExecutionPolicy Bypass` is a good habit to form to ensure predictable execution, *assuming that you trust the code you're invoking*.
- As [Compo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6738015/compo) points out, another good habit to form to ensure a predictable execution environment is to use `-NoProfile`, which bypasses loading of PowerShell's [profile files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Profiles). In addition to preventing potentially unnecessary / unwanted modifications of the execution environment by the profiles, bypassing profile loading also speeds up the command.

---

<sup>[1] Note that [`pwsh`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh), the *PowerShell (Core)* CLI, now defaults to `-File`.</sup>

Comment: I wasn't aware that there was a case whereby, `-ExecutionPolicy` was required for running a PowerShell `-Command`, as opposed to a PowerShell script _(`-File`)_. Am I wrong? And is it required in this case?

Comment: @mklement0 thank you! I want to ask one more thing. I tried pasting a powershell command in pastebin. The url is https://pastebin.com/raw/bNMQZW1C which in the post would be the urlExample. When i tried downloading it as in my example, i get an error of :
Exception calling "DownloadFile" with "2" argument(s) : "The given path's format is not supported." At line:1 char:195 + ... $WebClient.DownloadFile('https:\\pastebin.com\raw\bNMQZW1 ... + CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodINvocationException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NotSupportedException

Manually typing url ends in same error..

Comment: @Compo, you're right: it isn't required in _this case_, but please see my update for why you may want to use `-ExecutionPolicy` as a matter of habit.

Comment: @bd55, it sounds like the problem is with the _file-path_ argument, not the URL.

Comment: @mklement0 No :/ Even if i try 'C:\Users\testUser\Desktop\exampleFile.txt' it will display the same error. Also the error shows the first argument of DownloadFile, not the second (the path)

Comment: @bd55, please show the full `powershell.exe` command line. Note that your error message shows a _literal_ URL argument, not a reference to `$env:urlExample`

Comment: @mklement0 is there a chat or something we can talk so that i display the full code of what i am trying to achieve? Because comment section is about to get messy:P

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251979/discussion-between-mklement0-and-bd55).

Comment: Thanks for the updated information @mklement0. I figured there'd be occasions, _which I'd never seen explained_, hence my question to you, as I knew you'd be the best person to answer it. I suppose using `-NoProfile` should be included in these types of commands too, just to be sure that that there are no unnecesary modules imported/loaded too, and for a potential speed boost.

Comment: Thanks, @Compo. Good point about `-NoProfile` - please see my update.

Comment: @mklement0 i posted the full code in chat